# Run psql command with postgres role

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am try to run **psql** command with **postgres** role.

(1) `sudo psql -U postgres` Since **postgres** differs from my OS username, I receive the **Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"** error when I run it.

(2) But when I run `sudo -u postgres psql`, it succeeds

[My terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l27S.png)

I'm not sure how the (2) commands can work because, according to a Postgres document, peer authentication happens automatically locally and my current OS username is different from **postgres**. (I made no changes to pg_hba.config or pg_ident.config files.)

And what is the difference between the (1) and the (2) command?

Comment: Because in 2)  the `sudo -u postgres` is running the `psql` command as the `postgres` system user which then passes `peer` authentication. Add the content of your `pg_hba.conf` file **as text not an image** to your question.

Comment: The point of `sudo` is to change who your OS user is.  So, that is what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first attempt, you used `sudo` to become the `root` user (because there was no `-u` option) and tried to connect as database user `postgres`, which will fail with `peer` authentication because `root` is different from `postgres`.

In your second attempt, you used `sudo` to become user `postgres` and called `psql` without specifying a username, so that the username defaults to the same as your current operating system user name, namely `postgres`. Then `peer` authentication works.